# Plaid Api wont let me authenticate account with account/routing number

Tags: plaid

Using Plaid version "2020-09-14". I am following these instructions https://plaid.com/docs/auth/coverage/same-day/

I'm using node js to generate a link token and i successfully do:

```
        var plaid = require('plaid'); 
        const client = new plaid.Client({
            clientID: process.env.PLAID_CLIENT_ID,
            secret: process.env.PLAID_SECRET,
            env: process.env.PLAID_ENV
        });

        console.log('client is ',client)
        app.post('/api/create_link_token', async function (req, res) {
            try{
            const response = await client.createLinkToken({
                user: {
                client_user_id: '123-test-user-id',
                },
                client_name: 'Plaid Test App',
                products: ['auth'],
                country_codes: ['US'],
                webhook: 'https://webhook.example.com',
                language: 'en'
            })
            return res.send({link_token: response.link_token}) 
            
            } catch (error) {
            // handle error
            console.log('error',error)
            return res.send({err: error.message})
            }
        });
```

I get a link token everytime I run this. Then, i use said link token to try to authenticate the user's bank by using same day micro deposits (my company is setup for this through Plaid).

What keeps happening is the screen pops up that asks you to search for your bank and I do not want that. I want the screen to popup just like the one at the top of the page in the link I listed above. It asks the user for their name first, then routing, then account numbers.

How do I make the Plaid api show me the screen that prompts the user for their accounting/routing numbers without trying to authenticate them automatically with their bank username and password?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't, at least right now, using publicly released Plaid APIs. (You're not the first person to ask for this, and we're working on some stuff that should help, but it isn't yet available to the developer general public.)

Comment: The company I work for is a paying customer. So does that apply for paying customers too?

Comment: Possibly! If your company is an existing Plaid customer, you/they can contact their Plaid Account Manager to learn more and see if the company meets the eligibility criteria to access a pilot program for this feature.